# Stick items to bottom inside RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I want to have a `RecyclerView` that does order its items left to right and top to bottom as it does by default. But additionally I want following special behaviour like in the image below on the right side.

[image]

I want that the items "as a total" stick to bottom as if the `RecyclerView` itself would adjust its size to wrap its content if the items do not exceed the `RecyclerViews` height - for a better accessibility with the thumb for search results. I can't get this behaviour with a combination of `LayoutManager::reverseLayout` and `RecyclerView::layoutDirection` and `wrap_content` for the `RecyclerView` and mack it stick to the bottom does not work either because I want the whole list area to be scrollable (the `RecyclerView` must keep its full size)- any ideas how I can get this behaviour?

Comment: You could probably do this with top padding or dummy entries to fill the top rows. What shows in the unoccupied top area? Is there a grid pattern, as you show, or is it all blank? I assume you are using GridLayoutManager.

Comment: Correct, I use the `GridLayoutManager`. The grid only symbolises, that the items stick to the bottom in the special way and that the `RecyclerView` does not wrap its content. So the grid should be invisible in the end. Adding dummy items does work and I did like this until now - but I may do it this way because its the only solution that comes to my mind as well. Additionally, if you use items with different span counts the logic for the dummy item must take care of this but still it works.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my understanding of what you are trying to do.

1. The *RecyclerView* has some real estate on the screen that is constant in width and height for any given device/orientation.
2. If the item count is such that its display fills the *RecyclerView's* on-screen area, then the *RecyclerView* just fills the area and scrolls as it will.
3. If the item count is such that the  *RecyclerView's* on-screen area is not filled, then the whole display of the items should drop to the bottom of the *RecyclerView's* on-screen area leaving empty space at the top.

One way to do this is to programmatically set top padding to the *RecyclerView* that is the difference between the height of the *RecyclerView* and the total height of the displayed items if they don't fill the *RecyclerView*. This is easier if you can compute the height difference before layout, but you could also compute it after layout with a [global layout listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener).

[LinearLayoutManager#findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/LinearLayoutManager#findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()) will tell you which item is on top of the display.

[LinearLayoutManager#findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/LinearLayoutManager#findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()) will tell you the last position.

If all positions are shown, you will know to introduce top padding.

I am unclear if you would want the items to be able to scroll to the top or not if they don't fill the *RecyclerView*. Introduce bottom padding if they should scroll up leaving empty space at the bottom.

You will also have to specify `android:clipToPadding="false"` on the *RecyclerView* to get the padding to work as explained above.

Here is a sample activity to show how this can be done:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final List<String> mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView mRecycler;
    private final int mCount = 24;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        for (int i = 0; i < mCount; i++) {
            mItems.add("[" + i + "] " + getString(R.string.lorem));
        }

        mRecycler = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        RecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(mItems);
        mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mRecycler.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 5));

        mRecycler.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                mRecycler.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                GridLayoutManager glm = (GridLayoutManager) mRecycler.getLayoutManager();
                if (glm == null) return;
                int lastPosition = glm.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                if (lastPosition == (mCount - 1)) {
                    View lastView = glm.findViewByPosition(lastPosition);
                    if (lastView == null) return;
                    int newPadding = mRecycler.getHeight() - lastView.getBottom();
                    // Set bottom padding to newPadding to allow items to scroll to the top
                    // of the RecyclerView.
                    mRecycler.setPadding(0, newPadding, 0, newPadding);
                    mRecycler.setClipToPadding(false);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the idea - its quite simple but in my tests it does not work with recyclerview animations and filtering (the views won't be on their final position when the padding is calculated and animations will not work correctly). I think this can only be done in a custom layout manager correctly so dummy items + reverse data + reverse layout still seems to be my best and simplest option

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this behaviour to align all items to the bottom of RecyclerView you need to set the flag `setStackFromEnd(true)`

> When stack from bottom is set to true, the list fills its content
> starting from the bottom of the view

but this flag is not supported by the GridLayout throwing an exception like:

> GridLayoutManager does not support stack from end. Consider using
> reverse layout

but even using `setReverseLayout(true)` in GridLayoutManager it renders the items from bottom to top and from left to right which is not the result you want even reversing the data of your list.

**Possible Solutions:**

1. Use GridLayoutManager and add top padding only to the first columns to fill the remaining top area or even use dummy empty columns.
2. Use a LinearLayout with `setStackFromEnd(true)` which works as expected where each item is rendered from bottom to top of RecyclerView, and each item row (Item View) holding eg: 4 views (the number of columns) with equal width. Of course in that way each Item model in the list must hold 4 data one for each column.

If you choose the second option you can prepare your columns data for each row like the below code snippet:

```
List<ItemModel> data = new ArrayList<>();
int listCnt = 14;
for(int i=0; i<listCnt; i++){
    if(i%4 == 0) {
        String dataCol1 = i < listCnt ? String.valueOf(i) : "";
        String dataCol2 = (i + 1) < listCnt ? String.valueOf(i + 1) : "";
        String dataCol3 = (i + 2) < listCnt ? String.valueOf(i + 2) : "";
        String dataCol4 = (i + 3) < listCnt ? String.valueOf(i + 3) : "";
        data.add(new ItemModel(dataCol1, dataCol2, dataCol3, dataCol4));
    }
}

//set LinearLayoutManager
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

//set adapter
RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(data);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

where ItemModel holds the data for each row like:

```
public class ItemModel {

    public String dataCol1="", dataCol2="", dataCol3="", dataCol4="";

    public ItemModel(String dataCol1, String dataCol2, String dataCol3, String dataCol4) {
        this.dataCol1 = dataCol1;
        this.dataCol2 = dataCol2;
        this.dataCol3 = dataCol3;
        this.dataCol4 = dataCol4;
    }
}
```

And of course in your adapter you have to set the columns Visibility to `View.INVISIBLE` for those who don't have any data and `View.VISIBLE` for those who have.
Example of adapter can be like below:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

        private List<ItemModel> mData;

        public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<ItemModel> data) {
            this.mData = data;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list_row, parent, false);
            return new ItemViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
           ItemModel itemModel = mData.get(position);
           if(holder instanceof ItemViewHolder) {
               ((ItemViewHolder) holder).bind(itemModel);
           }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mData.size();
        }

        public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
            public TextView itemTextView1, itemTextView2, itemTextView3, itemTextView4;

            public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                itemTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemTextView1);
                itemTextView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemTextView2);
                itemTextView3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemTextView3);
                itemTextView4 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemTextView4);

                itemTextView1.setOnClickListener(this);
                itemTextView2.setOnClickListener(this);
                itemTextView3.setOnClickListener(this);
                itemTextView4.setOnClickListener(this);
            }

            public void bind(ItemModel itemModel){
                itemTextView1.setText(itemModel.dataCol1);
                itemTextView2.setText(itemModel.dataCol2);
                itemTextView3.setText(itemModel.dataCol3);
                itemTextView4.setText(itemModel.dataCol4);

                itemTextView1.setVisibility(TextUtils.isEmpty(itemModel.dataCol1) ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE);
                itemTextView2.setVisibility(TextUtils.isEmpty(itemModel.dataCol2) ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE);
                itemTextView3.setVisibility(TextUtils.isEmpty(itemModel.dataCol3) ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE);
                itemTextView4.setVisibility(TextUtils.isEmpty(itemModel.dataCol4) ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int cId = v.getId();
                if(cId == itemTextView1.getId()){
                    //get col1 data
                    String dataCol1 = mData.get(getAdapterPosition()).dataCol1;
                }
                else if(cId == itemTextView2.getId()){
                    //get col2 data
                    String dataCol2 = mData.get(getAdapterPosition()).dataCol2;
                }
                else if(cId == itemTextView3.getId()){
                    //get col3 data
                    String dataCol3 = mData.get(getAdapterPosition()).dataCol3;
                }
                else if(cId == itemTextView4.getId()){
                    //get col4 data
                    String dataCol4 = mData.get(getAdapterPosition()).dataCol4;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

where the list item `R.layout.item_list_row` which holds the 4 column views can be like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemTextView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        tools:text="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemTextView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        tools:text="2"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemTextView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        tools:text="3"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemTextView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        tools:text="4"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And of course if you have a different span count number you can make different ViewHolder types in the RecyclerView Adapter.

Results for option 2 with RecyclerView height to be `match_parent`, `300dp` and `wrap_content` respectively will be like below. RecyclerView has the grey background:

[image: match_parent]
[image: 300dp]
[image: wrap_content]

Comment: That's just a visual solution. Manually combining sub items is no good solution - you will lose default item handling, animations and more... I prefer `setReverseLayout` + inverse data + invisible dummy items at the end instead but this has small drawbacks as well... Still the best idea I have so far.